# BI Analysis report containing 'UNKNOWN' member in dimension

Tags: business-intelligence

My analysis report showing a unknown member with the dimension.
I verified with the columns not null or blank. Still having.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: inspite of down voting give the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1419/ssas-%E2%80%93-hiding-unknown-member
This is I got to hide the unknown member data of dimension, but still won't get the unknown data. 
Better than before, to hide the data from report.